# Slide-in sidebar with fluid container widths

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to emulate the search activated sidebar as shown in the images. The sidebar needs to slide in from the left and 'compress' (compress thing is cracking me up) the fluid width container and needs to be visible by default on mobiles (I have this part figured out using media queries). I am using bootstrap and JQuery for my project. I have tried multiple solutions but all of them failed miserably.

Going into the detail, I have a row of 2 'col-lg-6'. I want this to compress down to a single file when the search bar is clicked. I have everything figured out other than the way to compress it.

Here are the images.

[search active and inactive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt6CS.png)

And here's the link to [my miserable attempt](http://umbracreations.com/sidebar-test/).

EDIT: I have been trying a new approach involving a responsive grid and an off canvas search bar. Seems to be headed in the right direction.

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail and show us the code what you have tried so that we can help you

Comment: I have already linked it to the test version of the site. The code is quite long to post here. Besides, that attempt shouldn't be of much help either. Thank you for your willingness to help!